# What's the best way to iterate through this structure in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, etsy

I'm new to rails and having trouble figuring out how to iterate through this data. This is the output from a gem that integrates the etsy API. It looks like an array of sets of hashes, maybe?

```
output=[#<Etsy::Listing:0x5551ba8 @result={"listing_id"=>182661496, "title"=>"Edible Butterflies in Coral", "quantity"=>1, "price"=>"12.50", "ending_tsz"=>1405362199, "shipping_template_id"=>nil, "MainImage"=>{"url_75x75"=>"https://img1.etsystatic.com/036/0/8545731/il_75x75.576542775_ibud.jpg"}}, @token="token", @secret="secret">, 
#<Etsy::Listing:0x5551bc0 @result={"listing_id"=>182671909, "title"=>"Marshmallow Sampler Pack", "quantity"=>3, "price"=>"9.50", "ending_tsz"=>1405362468, "shipping_template_id"=>1680751676, "MainImage"=>{"url_75x75"=>"https://img1.etsystatic.com/021/0/8545731/il_75x75.576544537_n2zo.jpg"}}, @token="token", @secret="secret">, 
#<Etsy::Listing:0x5551bf0 @result={"listing_id"=>182663346, "title"=>"Gourmet popcorn and seasoning kit", "quantity"=>15, "price"=>"26.95", "ending_tsz"=>1405363087, "shipping_template_id"=>nil, "MainImage"=>{"url_75x75"=>"https://img0.etsystatic.com/026/0/8545731/il_75x75.576428850_r1mv.jpg"}}, @token="token", @secret">, 
#<Etsy::Listing:0x5551c08 @result={"listing_id"=>189414412, "title"=>"Sailor Tote Bag", "quantity"=>45, "price"=>"50.00", "ending_tsz"=>1410586221, "shipping_template_id"=>1024284528, "MainImage"=>{"url_75x75"=>"https://img0.etsystatic.com/039/0/8545731/il_75x75.576443100_slse.jpg"}}, @token="token", @secret="secret">]
```

Nothing I've tried seems to work. Treating it as an array works for some things, like: output.length correctly returns *4*. But output[0] returns *<Etsy::Listing:0x5483418>* without any of the other data. All I actually need is what's contained in @result={}. Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `output.first.result`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you missed to read [this in doc](https://github.com/kytrinyx/etsy#listings):

```
listings = output.map do |listing| 
  { 
    "title"    => listing.title, 
    "quantity" => listing.quantity, 
    "price"    => listing.price
  }
end
```

Comment: @wickedpixel Make sure you accept an answer(whichever helped you) so that it can help others in future.

Comment: quick follow-up - how do I get the key/value pairs from MainImage? I tried `listing.MainImage.each_pair {|k,v| puts "#{k.inspect}: #{v}" }` but that just results in `NoMethodError undefined method 'MainImage'`

Comment: did you try `listing.image`? see [the allowed list of attributes here](https://github.com/kytrinyx/etsy/blob/master/lib/etsy/listing.rb#L38-L49).

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> It looks like an array of sets of hashes, maybe?

**It's an array of objects.** Each object is an `Etsy::Listing` instance. You should be able to do this on the Rails console:

```
> listing = output.first
#=> <Etsy::Listing:0x5483418>
> listing.result
#=> {"listing_id"=>182661496, …}
```

If you want to do something with each listing, you could do this:

```
> output.each {|listing| puts listing.result.title }
Edible Butterflies in Coral
Marshmallow Sampler Pack
Gourmet popcorn and seasoning kit
Sailor Tote Bag
>
```

Comment: @wickedpixel If an answer works well for you, please upvote it. You can and should upvote any answer you find useful. Thanks!